Realizar una consulta SQL desde conexión a datos externos en Excel desde una hoja del mismo
Quisiera hacer referencia a una hoja de Excel (2010 standard 32 bits) en la cual tengo una lista, para ejecutar un comando SQL desde propiedades de conexión a una base de datos.
Ejemplo del comando:
Select*from clientes where id_cliente in (aquí iria el listado a consultar que lo tengo en una hoja de Excel)
Sé que se puede hacer por macros, pero necesito que sea por conexión a datos externos ya que muestra una tabla dinámica que se usa para actualizar un informe.
Muchas gracias.


Bienvenido a SO en español. Lo que quieres es actualizar tu instrucción SQL con valores en celdas. De manera directa no se puede sin utilizar VBA. No obstante, sobre la teoría se podría hacer si utilizas PowerQuery y defines rangos con nombres. aquí tienes un ejemplo
